# Redirecting after user authentication in Angular2 and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to redirect the user after the Sign In is successful but for some reasons I can't make it happen. I tried multiple ways but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. 
I am using Angular 2 latest version with Firebase database.

Also any suggestion if my code can be improved, that would be great :)

Thank you,
Appreciated

auth.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { User } from "./user.interface";
declare var firebase: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService{
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  redirectURL: string;

  signupUser(user: User) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  signinUser(user: User) {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
  }
  logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      if(user){
          return true;
      } else {
          return false
      }
  }
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) { return true; }

        // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
        this.authService.redirectURL = url;

        // Navigate to the login page if the user access Guarded pages
        this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in the the browser console? I haven't used Firebase myself yet but I'm pretty sure some calls are async. Are you sure the authentication state is already known when `checkLogin()` is executed?

Comment: No, i dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **promise** based sign in to detect when you have successfully signed in, to reroute to your logged in page.

```
signinUser(user: User) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((userInfo) => {
      // You are now logged in
      // Maybe redirect to the first logged in page
      // this.router.navigate([ 'whatever' ]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Ran into some issues
      // Maybe report the error on your sign in page
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I show the error message on my AppComponent ?

Comment: Assuming you want to report the error through this service it won't be a simple answer. If you formally ask the question on stackoverflow, and link to it on the comment, I can respond to it there!